# Create function that creates and return a list of multiples of a number

Tags: c#

so I am super new to c# and to programming in general. Anyways I am trying to create a function that creates and returns a list of multiples of a number. For example, MultiplesOf(3,5), where the 3 is the starting number and 5 is the number of multiples, would result in {3, 6, 9, 12, 15}. This is what I have so far:

```cs
private static double[] MultiplesOf(double number, int length)     
{
    List<int> results = new List<int>();                           
    // TODO Problem 1 Start                                        
    for (int i = 1; i <= length; i++)                             
    {
        if ( i % number == 0)                                     
            results.Add(i);                                        
    }
    return results;                                                
}
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appricated!

Comment: You are declaring your function to return a `double[]`, but then you `return results` which is a `List<int>`. You either return an array of doubles or a list of int.

Comment: Hi and welcome tto StackOverflow. We need a question and a problem description to be able to help. This is how this forum works.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of *dividing* the `length` by the current number `i`, why not just *add* the `number` to the previous `number`? Multiplying something is nothing different than just adding it again and again, is it? So the term `3 * 3` is the same like `3 + 3 + 3`.

```
List<int> results = new List<int>();                           
// TODO Problem 1 Start                                        
for ( int i = 1; i <= length; i++)                             
{                     
    number += number;                                         
    result.Add(number);                                         
}                                                              
return results;
```

Apart from this your method should return `List<int>`, instead of `double[]`.

Comment: I think you would need a separate variable to hold the 'current' number. This accumulates quickly.

Answer (score 1):

you just need to multiply the length[i] by the number you want to find the multiples on.

```
public List<int> MultiplesOf(int number, int length)     
{                                                                  
      List<int> results = new List<int>();  
      for ( int i = 1; i <= length; i++)                                                                                         
      {    
          results.Add(i * number);
      }                                                              
      return results;                                                
    }                                                                                                             
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for ( int i = 1; i <= length; i++)                             
  {                                                                                           
          results.Add(i*number);                                        
  }                                                              
  return results;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the return type of the method to array of double. please try this way

```
private static double[] MultiplesOf(double number, int length)
    {
        //return type of the method is array of double data type, so we are declaring the return variable with double[] datatype.
        double[] results = new double[length];
                                              
        for (int i = 1; i <= length; i++)
        {
            //instead of mod operation, you need to multiply the number and add to array.
            results[i-1] = (number*i);
        }
        return results;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your function like below:

```bash
    public static List<int> MultiplesOf(int number, int length)
    {
        List<int> results = new List<int>();
        // TODO Problem 1 Start                                        
        for (int i = 1; results.Count <= length - 1; i++)
        {
            if (i % number == 0)
                results.Add(i);
        }
        return results;
    }
```

This for loop above makes length times control. If you want a more performance way you can modify your function like this:

```bash
    public static List<int> MultiplesOf(int number, int length)
    {
        List<int> results = new List<int>();
        // TODO Problem 1 Start                                        
        for (int i = 1; results.Count <= length - 1; i++)
        {
            results.Add(i * number);
        }
        return results;
    }
```

For see the output

```bash
var x = MultiplesOf(3,5);

foreach (var item in x)
{
    Console.Write($"{item}, ");
}
```